# Initialization datatable via Ajax - No data displayed

Tags: ajax, laravel, datatable, datatables

I have a datatable that I would like to initialize with an Ajax call http://url/api/v1/shocks

**table.blade.php**

```
<div class="card-body p-0">
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-striped table-md" id="table-raw-shocks" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Record Id</th>
                    <th>Count</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Amplitude 1 (G)</th>
                    <th>Amplitude 2 (G)</th>
                    <th>Time 1 (s)</th>
                    <th>Time 2 (s)</th>
                    <th>Freq 1 (Hz)</th>
                    <th>Freq 2 (Hz)</th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <th>Record Id</th>
                    <th>Count</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Amplitude 1 (G)</th>
                    <th>Amplitude 2 (G)</th>
                    <th>Time 1 (s)</th>
                    <th>Time 2 (s)</th>
                    <th>Freq 1 (Hz)</th>
                    <th>Freq 2 (Hz)</th>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript part**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        initShocksActivityTable();

    });

    function initShocksActivityTable() {
        var url = '{{ route("api:v1:shocks.index") }}'; //http://url/api/v1/shocks

        var table = $('#table-raw-shocks-all').DataTable({
            responsive: true,
            responsive: {
                details: {
                    type: "column",
                    target: "tr"
                }
            },
            orderCellsTop: true,
            fixedHeader: true,
            dom: "Bfrtip",
            buttons: ["copy", "csv", "excel", "pdf", "print"],
            columnDefs: [{
                sortable: true
            }],
            "ajax": url,
            "columns": [{
                    "data": "attributes.record_id"
                },
                {
                    "data": "attributes.count"
                },
                {
                    "data": "attributes.date_time"
                },
                {
                    "data": "attributes.amplitude_1"
                },
                {
                    "data": "attributes.amplitude_2"
                },
                {
                    "data": "attributes.time_1"
                },
                {
                    "data": "attributes.time_2"
                },
                {
                    "data": "attributes.freq_1"
                },
                {
                    "data": "attributes.freq_2"
                },

            ],
            lengthMenu: [
                [10, 25, 50, -1],
                [10, 25, 50, "All"]
            ],
            iDisplayLength: 10,
            order: [
                [2, "desc"]
            ]

        });
    }
```

My data looks like this :
[image]

Attributes contains all the necessary data that I would like to add on my datatable.

[image]

When I do that, I have no data displayed. I suspect that it is because, my data is an array ( [0], [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNbs2.jpg)...)
I tried to add this piece of code (https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.dataSrc)

```
 "dataSrc": "data.attributes"
```

But it still does not work.

I'm sure, it's something that I missed but I have some difficulties to find what is the problem to fetch correctly the data.

Could you please help me on that ? Thank

Comment: Based on your screenshots, it looks like you need to use `"dataSrc": "data"` to point DataTables to the starting point of the array it needs to iterate over. That will require you to re-work your `ajax` section, so the `dataSrc` can be added there. And then for each column's data attribute, you will need to use `"data": "attributes.record_id"` and so on.

Comment: Having said that, please do not post screenshots of data. Instead, edit your question to show a sample of the actual JSON, formatted for readability. That is much easier to review - thanks!